# CSS button issue in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, button, twitter-bootstrap

Here original source (with problem)

http://goo.gl/UjcoC

[image]

But when I try to regenerate issue in jsfiddle getting correct result

http://goo.gl/uhGP0

[image]

What am I missing? How to fix this issue?

Comment: create style `.btn .caret{height: 8px;}`

Comment: Fyi, it's "recommend" with two "m"

Answer (score 1):

```
display: inline-block;
```

on the caret class is preventing your span to stretch the button.
Fix:

```
.btn .caret {
    display: inline;
    top: 10px;
    margin-left: 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: but I can't find this css rule inside my css files

Answer (score 1):

> ### Requires HTML5 doctype
>
> Bootstrap makes use of certain HTML elements and CSS properties that
> require the use of the HTML5 doctype. Include it at the beginning of
> all your projects.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  ...
</html>
```

Taken from (the very start of) [the documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#global).